# db.create_all() doesn't create a database in a desired directory

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database for my Flask application in the main directory of my project. This is my code for initializing a database:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///users.db'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Flask requires application context, so this is how I create the database:

```
$ flask shell
>>> db.create_all()
```

I also tried doing it with:

```
$ python
>>> from app import app, db
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> db.create_all()
```

Both of these options create the database in the */instance* directory. Is there any way to get around this and create it in the main directory of the project?

Answer (score 3):

The [instance path](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#instance-folders) is the preferred and default location for the database. I recommend you to use this one for security reasons. However, it is also possible to choose an alternative solution in which the full length of the path is specified in the configuration.

The following configuration corresponds to an outdated variant, where the database is created in the current working directory. Please don't use this anymore.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ='sqlite:///' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'users.db')
```

This corresponds to the current solution.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ='sqlite:///' + os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'users.db')
```