# Flask SQLAlchemy Can't Connect to Database in a short way

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy, directory, database-connection

I have code for database connection:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/aoivanov/Documents/FlaskMarket/market/market.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

There are 2 connections for understanding but I can't connect to a DB with the short way, only with an absolute link to the DB.

Can someone explain why?

I expect to get connection to db

Comment: I don't think the two paths point to the same place. The second variant points to the [instance folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/#instance-folders), while this is not the case with the first solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [db.create\_all() doesn't create a database in a desired directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171824/db-create-all-doesnt-create-a-database-in-a-desired-directory)

Comment: The matter is that I pass course and repeat everything in video and the way 'sqlite:///market.db' points on root folder in project. In project everything on video everything woks good, but on my laptop I need point clearly full way to connect to db. 
I had the same issue during my another project. Can't understand why...

Comment: The location where the database is created is version dependent. You may be working on your laptop with a newer version.