# No Database file being created with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and Flask to generate a database like so:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"
```

```
abs_instance_path = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'instance'))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
db.init_app(app)

...

create_database(app)
```

```
def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
            print("Database created!")
```

However, I cannot find my actual database.db file.
It should be in an instance folder I believe within the project directory. As an update I have now found it in C:\Users<my profile>\var\website-instance, so no clue why it is there, or what puts it there.

Each time I hit run I also get the "Database created!" message showing the program did not find it in the specified folder either :/

I'm really at a loss as to how to proceed.

I have tried manually setting my instance folder and cloning my project to see if it works elsewhere, all to no avail.

I have worked with flask before and have always had no problems with database files, though I could be missing something very obvious, thank you for any help

GitHub: https://github.com/Ricy40/HolidayRentalSite

Edit: I have located my database file now it is for whatever reason under:
C:\Users<profile>\var\website-instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [db.create\_all() doesn't create a database in a desired directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171824/db-create-all-doesnt-create-a-database-in-a-desired-directory)