# db.create_all() is not creating/genrating the .db file

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on flask and trying to create a sql lite database with the following commands
in my python terminal -

```
>>> from app import db
>>> from app import app
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> db.create_all()
```

these commands are not creating the .db file for me

this is my python code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///todo.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ToDo(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.sno} - {self.title}"

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')
    # return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/products')
def products():
    return 'This is products page'

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oA8brF3w5XQ

Comment: How do you know it is not being created? Have you searched? (it may not be created where you expect). Did you receive any error messages.

Comment: [Also  relevant](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/config/#connection-url-format)

Comment: i did not receive any error messages but it should be created in the folder where my app.py file is present. I know it's not being created because it's not visible to me in my directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [db.create\_all() doesn't create a database in a desired directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171824/db-create-all-doesnt-create-a-database-in-a-desired-directory)

Comment: no it does not solve my issue, as it says to me -

 "message": "\"os\" is not defined",
 "source": "Pylance",

Comment: In your solution, the [`instance_path`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#instance-folders) is already used to create the database. If you want to use [`os.path.join(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to specify the path as in the referenced example, you have to import the module with `import os`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the Flask application context and call `db.create_all()` without using the `with` keyword, but it's generally recommended to use `with app.app_context()` for managing the context correctly, especially when dealing with database operations. Using `with` ensures that the context is properly set up and torn down when it's no longer needed, which is crucial for resource management and avoiding potential issues.

```
>>> from app import app
>>> from app import db 
>>> with app.app_context():
...     db.create_all()
...
>>>
```

Comment: not working at all